# Show that $\log({n\choose n/2})=O(n)$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis, asymptotics

Show that $\log({n\choose n/2})=O(n)$,
I've tried to use stirling's formula but didn't get any close

Comment: Can you show us how you used Stirling's formula? Even a weak version of it suffices to prove what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}=\frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{2}!\right)^2}$$
$$\log \left(\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\right)=\log(n!)-2\log \left(\frac{n}{2}!\right)$$

Use Stirling approximation twice and continue with Taylor expansion.